# Error trying to find most recent file and copy it

Tags: vbscript

I'm getting "Object required" runtime error when trying to run the following code. I am trying to find the most recent file saved in a folder and copy/rename it to another file name. My issue is the If statement to "Check for most recent file in folder" is returning Object errors.

I have followed other suggestions on here, but I can't seem to get over the Object error hurdles. If anyone can provide help for this newbie, I would appreciate it.

```
Option Explicit
Dim FSO, FSO2, FLD, FIL
Dim strFolder, strContent, strPath, tmpName, tmpName2, mostRecent, newfile

strFolder = "C:\Users\username\Documents\Mockup"

'Create the filesystem object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set FSO2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'loop through the folder and get the files
For Each FLD in FSO.GetFolder(strFolder).SubFolders
    'Reset mostRecent to nothing 
    Set mostRecent = Nothing
    Set mostRecent = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")        

    For Each Fil In FLD.Files
        If Fil = FLD & "\import.ARCHIVE" Then
            FSO2.DeleteFile FLD & "\import.ARCHIVE"
            Fil = FLD & "\import.tra"
        End If

        If Fil = FLD & "\import.tra" Then
            tmpName = Replace(Fil, "import.tra", "import.ARCHIVE")'Replace(String, thisString, toThisString)
            'Name Fil as tmpName
            FSO.MoveFile Fil, tmpName
        End If

        'Check for most recent file in folder
        If mostRecent Is Nothing Then
            Set mostRecent = Fil
        ElseIf Fil.DateCreated > mostRecent.DateCreated Then
            Set mostRecent = Fil
        End If

        tmpName2 = Replace(mostRecent, "*.*", "import.tra")'Replace(String, thisString, toThisString)
        FSO2.CopyFile mostRecent, tmpName2            
    Next
Next

'Clean up
Set FLD = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
Set FSO2 = Nothing
Set mostRecent = Nothing
```

Comment: Please show the exact error message and the line that raises the error.

Answer (score 0):

just mask `Set mostRecent = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` will do.

We don't need a File System Object to get the date created for a file. I think you just mean to create an object. In vbscript, since you already 'dim mostRecent', when using `Set`, it will automatically assigned to an object.

Hope this will help you :)